# Is it possible to migrate Mylyn tasks from the local repository to Bugzilla?

Tags: eclipse, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn, connector

I just set up a free Bugzilla account at [bugheaven.com](http://www.bugheaven.com) and was hoping to migrate my existing local Mylyn repository tasks to Bugzilla.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bulk copy available, but you can use New / Clone Task... from popup menu in the Task List view.